# Cannot get Diesel to infer a nullable Timestamp column in a SQLite table

Tags: sqlite, rust, rust-diesel

I'm trying to use Diesel's inference capability to work with a SQLite table that contains a nullable timestamp column. A complete example is available in [an older revision](https://github.com/nmusatti/diesel_timestamp_error/tree/3dfc19658490ae3200e94067108c38a95b3f6a0e) of this [GitHub project](https://github.com/nmusatti/diesel_timestamp_error).

The `books` table is defined as follows:

```sql
create table books (
    id integer not null primary key,
    title varchar null,
    save_date timestamp null 
)
```

I'm trying to query it with the following struct:

```rust
pub mod domain {
    use chrono::naive;

    #[derive(Queryable)]
    pub struct Book {
        id : i32,
        title : Option<String>,
        save_date : Option<naive::NaiveDateTime>, 
    }
}
```

However when I try to actually perform the query, as in:

```rust
fn main() {
    use self::schema::books::dsl::*;
    let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL").unwrap();
    let conn = sqlite::SqliteConnection::establish(&database_url).unwrap();
    let res = books.load::<domain::Book>(&conn);
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::option::Option<chrono::NaiveDateTime>: diesel::types::FromSqlRow<diesel::types::Nullable<diesel::types::Timestamp>, _>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:32:21
   |
32 |     let res = books.load::<domain::Book>(&conn);
   |                     ^^^^ the trait `diesel::types::FromSqlRow<diesel::types::Nullable<diesel::types::Timestamp>, _>` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<chrono::NaiveDateTime>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <std::option::Option<chrono::naive::date::NaiveDate> as diesel::types::FromSqlRow<diesel::types::Nullable<diesel::types::Date>, DB>>
             <std::option::Option<chrono::naive::time::NaiveTime> as diesel::types::FromSqlRow<diesel::types::Nullable<diesel::types::Time>, DB>>
             <std::option::Option<chrono::naive::datetime::NaiveDateTime> as diesel::types::FromSqlRow<diesel::types::Nullable<diesel::types::Timestamp>, DB>>
             <std::option::Option<bool> as diesel::types::FromSqlRow<diesel::types::Nullable<diesel::types::Bool>, DB>>
           and 26 others
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::types::FromSqlRow<(diesel::types::Integer, diesel::types::Nullable<diesel::types::Text>, diesel::types::Nullable<diesel::types::Timestamp>), _>` for `(i32, std::option::Option<std::string::String>, std::option::Option<chrono::NaiveDateTime>)`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Queryable<(diesel::types::Integer, diesel::types::Nullable<diesel::types::Text>, diesel::types::Nullable<diesel::types::Timestamp>), _>` for `domain::Book`
```

What I don't understand is why the implementation for `chrono::naive::datetime::NaiveDateTime`
isn't picked up and what I should do to make it happen.

I'm using the stable toolchain, which is currently 1.18.0, and these are my dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4.0"
diesel = { version = "0.13.0", features = [ "chrono", "sqlite" ] }
diesel_codegen = { version = "0.13.0", features = [ "sqlite" ] }
dotenv = "0.9.0"
```

Comment: I added my dependencies to the original post. As you can see the ``chrono`` feature is defined for ``diesel``. It isn't available for ``diesel_codegen``.

Comment: The hint is in the error. The trait is implemented for `NaiveDateTime` but not `Option<NaiveDateTime>` (not that I can see in the Diesel documentation anyway). How you go about implementing it I am unsure - I've not played with Diesel for very long. Perhaps try removing the `Option` to begin with to make sure that is the issue.

Comment: Did you run the migration to setup the SQLite database? Otherwise schema inference won't work

Comment: The error message mentions ``<std::option::Option<chrono::naive::datetime::NaiveDateTime> as diesel::types::FromSqlRow<diesel::types::Nullable<diesel::types::Timestamp>, DB>>`` which should match except for the ``datetime`` module, which is private.

Comment: It should be noted that this question is not a duplicate. This error has nothing to do with multiple conflicting dependencies.  The "duplicate" designation should be removed.